# How to use SVM to classify while the features are extracted using CNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm, conv-neural-network

```
   conv12 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up12)
   conv12 = Dropout(0.3)(conv12)
   conv12 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv12)
   
   conv13 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv12)

   model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv13])

   model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=.00045), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])

   return model
```

After the conv13 layer i want to use SVM, how can i do that? I am new to this and can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Your neural network produces an output given an input (an image I assume). This output, as you set it to be the parameters from the `conv13` layer, will be a vector of a certain size. You can now consider this output as input for your SVM classifier. However, you do not need to stick to `Keras` for this step, as libraries like `scikit-learn` have implemented an easier way to do that.

Let's say your CNN produces a set of vectors like `X =[95, 25, ..., 45, 24]` as output. If you then have a set of labels `y = {0, 1}` then you can do:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

clf = SVC() # Play with hyperparameters.

clf.predict([[95, 25, ..., 45, 24]]) # Output: array([1])
```

See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I am having a hard time implementing it.
y = [0, 1]
svm = SVR(kernel="rbf", gamma="scale", C=1.0)
svm.fit(conv13, y)
what am i doing wrong here? when i run this above code i get this
__array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
I am noob.